# JIRA and JQL: How can I filter results where custom fields are not empty?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I'm working on a get request that gives me all JIRA issues with the custom field "Sponsor". Since it's an optional field, the value is often empty. So out of all issues in a JIRA project, how can I extract those who have a sponsor? My query looks like this so far

```
https://jira.companyname.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=projectname&maxResults=1000
```

What is missing? I do know the customField name and id.

I tried

```
jql=project=projectname&maxResults=1000&customfield_number!%3DEMPTY
```

and

```
jql=project=projectname&maxResults=1000&customfield_number!%3Dnull
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `is not EMPTY` in your JQL query, rather than `!= null` or `!=EMPTY`.

Substitute `number` for your custom field number and try this request URL: `https://jira.companyname.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=cf%5Bnumber%5D%20is%20not%20EMPTY`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunantely I still see null values in my json for this field...

Comment: Thanks for following up with the update - glad things worked out in the end!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out thanks to [someone who helped me in another forum](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-do-I-filter-custom-fields-with-value-null-in-URL-query/qaq-p/2110747).
The problem was that I treated the customfield parameter not as one in the jql query... So Adil's answer was correct, my problem was that I put `cf%5Bnumber%5D%20is%20not%20EMPTY`in the final part of the query. after maxResults.

Final URL that works for me looks like this:

```
https://jira.companyname.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=key+and+cf[id]+is+not+empty&maxResults=1000
```